NSwag - Can I store multiple accounts within swagger UI somehow?
Im using NSwag to generate swagger UI for an ASP.NET server with JWT authentication like so
settings.OperationProcessors.Add(new OperationSecurityScopeProcessor("Account Token"));
settings.DocumentProcessors.Add(new SecurityDefinitionAppender("Account Token",
    new NSwag.OpenApiSecurityScheme()
    {
        Type = NSwag.OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.Http,
        In = NSwag.OpenApiSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header,
        Scheme = "bearer",
        BearerFormat = "jwt"
    }));

I have 2 different types of accounts ("Seller" and "Buyer") that can access the same endpoints. the behavior is different depending on the account.
Right now I'm trying to test a bunch of endpoints for both accounts using the swagger UI, which is involving a lot of manually swapping out the token in my header.
Is there an easy way around this?
